# Cassandra 3.xのSecondary Indexのディスク使用量の見積りに関して

Tags: apache, database, cassandra

Cassandra 3.xのSecondary Indexのディスク使用量の見積りで困っています。
DataStaxのcommiterであるTyler Hobbs氏が0.7に関しては以下の様に回答しています。

> Their size will roughly be:
>   (cardinality of the set of indexed values * the avg size of the index values) + (the number of keys in the indexed column family * the avg size of keys in the column family).
>   Nodes only index rows that are stored locally -- that is, only rows for which they are a replica.

ここでの(the number of keys in the indexed column family * the avg size of keys in the column family)
で使用されているkeysはインデックス作成対象テーブルのPrimary Keyに含まれるカラムという認識で正しいでしょうか。
また、これはVer3.xでも有効でしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

Cassandraのセカンダリーインデックスは転置インデックスです。
例えば、以下のようなテーブルがあり、

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id text,
    name text,
    group text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

このテーブルにインデックスを作成します。

```
CREATE INDEX users_by_group ON users (group);
```

すると、Cassandraの各ノードは、そのノードが保持しているusersテーブルのデータに対して以下のような内部テーブルを作成します。

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_group (
    user_id text,
    group text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((group), user_id)
);
```

そして、インデックスを用いたSELECTの際に、インデックスのテーブルをまず検索し、元テーブルのプライマリーキー情報を取得します。
そして、取得したプライマリーキーで改めて、元テーブルを検索します。

したがって、質問にある

> ここでの(the number of keys in the indexed column family * the avg size of keys in the column family)で使用されているkeysはインデックス作成対象テーブルのPrimary Keyに含まれるカラムという認識で正しいでしょうか。

keys はおっしゃる通りPrimary Keyに含まれるカラムです。
この構造は Ver3.x でも変わっていません。

Comment: yukimさん 御丁寧な回答をありがとうございます。
大変助かります。 この例で言うと
( [groupのcardinality] * [groupの値の平均長] ) + ( 元テーブルの行数 * [user_idの平均長] )
という事なのですね、理解できました。 数日前から予備知識ゼロで初めてCassandraを調査しているのですが、
何分、資料が少なく古いバージョンに対するものが多いので、困っていました。 ここにも初めて投稿しました。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @unun soso 質問者とは ID が異なるようですが、もしアカウントが二つに分かれてしまった場合には [ヘルプを参考にアカウントのマージを検討してください。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)